# Python: Creating a Single Integer From Two Integers?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm searching for a simple algorithm that 'combines' two 2bytes integers into one unique 4bytes integer.

The two 2bytes integers are both whole positive numbers in the range `0..65535`.

I want to create *one* 4bytes integer that is the exact combination of both, in a way that will make it easy to:

**(1)** given the two 2bytes integers --> calculate the value of that 4bytes integer.

**(2)** given the 4bytes integer --> parse the contents of the two 2bytes integers.

Any idea how to achieve this in `python`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about:

```
def combine(n, m):
    return (n << 16) | m

def extract(c):
    return (c >> 16), c & 0xffff
```

This solution places one of the 2-byte integers in the upper half of a 32-bit word, and the other into the lower half. In order to extract the values, simply take the upper half of the word (`c >> 16`), and the lower half (`c & 0xffff`).

Comment: Dirk, your score is lower than Ignacio, hence I am choosing your answer as the winning one. Although both are very good.

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> i1, i2 = 345, 12
>>> i1 * 0x10000 + i2
22609932
>>> divmod(22609932, 0x10000)
(345, 12)
```

Comment: @user3262424, consider whether you care about safety when n or m are signed, or either of their magnitude is larger than 16 bits. (If i1 is float, i1 * 0x10000 will also taint the lower 16 bits.)